# charging gateway in j2me midp 1.0

Tags: mobile, java-me, sim-card

I am developing one application in j2me which requires charging gateway integration in j2me means.

Is there any way to deduct sim card balance directly?

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. There is no way to find the balance amount directly. For alternative, Get the response from gateway whether its successful or not.